# Has there ever been a peaceful vote to determine who sits on the Throne?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Has there ever been a peaceful vote to determine who sits on the Throne? 
I have the following criteria:

- The vote may be preceded by a battle.
- The vote must include multiple candidates.
- The voters must consist of multiple people (but not necessarily many, A, B and C electing D would suffice).

Answers may be based on the books or the TV series.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't ask this on Politics instead?

Comment: @Adamant Politics doesn't do fictional stuff.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Three times in history, [The Great Council](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Great_Council) was summoned to peacefully determine who shall rule

- Great Council of 101 AC

  King [Jaehaerys the wise](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_I_Targaryen) ruled during half a century, from 48 AC to 103 AC. During his reign, he had lot of diferent heirs. When Baelon, his designed heir, died in 101, he followed the advice of his son, the Archmaester Vaegon. A thousand noble came to the Capital, and Jaehaerys follow the Great Council decison by naming Viserys the new Prince of Dragonstone.
- Great Council of 136 AC

  This great council followed the [Dance of the Dragons](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dance_of_the_Dragons), a civil war between diferent Targaryens. Both claiants died, and the war ended in 131 AC, with Aegon III Targaryen as the new king . However, he was only eleven, and the regency was very conflictious during five years. in 136, a Great Council was summoned again to choose the regents
- Great Council of 233 AC

  in 233 AC, [Maekar I Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maekar_I_Targaryen) died during the Peake Uprising, and his heir was unclear. After some troubled times, the counxil elected Aegon V as the new heir, who would be named "Aegon the Unlikely", as he was the fourth son of a fourth son.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In addition to the examples in the accepted answer, S08E06 showed a meeting in which Bran was elected king. A shot of those taking part in the meeting:
[image]

From [screenrant.com](https://screenrant.com/game-thrones-finale-king-election-every-character/):

> Game of Thrones' finale saw the election of a new King, which involved a meeting of various characters new and old. Bran Stark is King of Westeros as the show ended, a position he got not through blood or conquest like his predecessors but via election.

Comment: I for one welcome our new robotic teen-boy overlord.